# Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context kotllin error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

> I want to create user register service ,Store the data in mongodb But
> when I pass all the required data in user build function I get some
> issue like Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are
> allowed in this context at the builder function but I am not sure how
> store user provide data in Mongodb, Here is the my code patter for
> register user but it not working it throw an error type like below

```
Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context



@PostMapping(value = ["/users"], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun createUser(@RequestBody payload: Signup): ResponseEntity<*>? {
        log.info("creating user {}", payload.username)
        val user: User = User
            .builder()
            .username= payload.username
            .email=payload.email
            .password=payload.password
            .userProfile(
                Profile
                    .builder()
                    .displayName=payload.name
                    .profilePictureUrl=payload.profilePicUrl
                    .build()
            )
            .build()
        try {
            userService.registerUser(user, Role.USER)
        } catch (e: UserNameAlreadyExistException) {
            throw BadRequestException(e.message)
        } catch (e: EmailAlreadyExistException) {
            throw BadRequestException(e.message)
        }
        val location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
            .fromCurrentContextPath().path("/users/{username}")
            .buildAndExpand(user.userName).toUri()
        return ResponseEntity
            .created(location)
            .body(ApiResponse(true, "User registered successfully"))
    }
```

> builder Function is not supported in userService.I do not  understand
> which type of Builder Function to import. in suggestion it shows lot
> of import suggestion .I use MongoDb as a database and springboot as
> frame  work

Comment: did the below answer help?

Answer (score 1):

```
User
  .builder()
  .username= payload.username
  .email=payload.email
```

This is incorrect syntax, you cannot have assignment and later access next variable with dot operator.

Here are few alternatives in Kotlin

The setter methods in kotlin can be used using property access syntax. You can replace property access syntax with actual setter methods. Each setter method in Builder returns the current instance of Builder back, hence you can chain multiple setters in single line

```
 User
    .builder()
    .setUsername(payload.username)
    .setEmail(payload.email).build()
```

Use `also` function to set multiple variables. The lambda passed to also function will get the Builder instance and use the setter method using property access syntax

```
User.builder().apply{
   username = payload.username
   email = payload.email
}.build()
```

For better understanding, divide the statement into multiple lines

```
 var userBuilder = User.Builder()
 userBuilder = userBuilder.setUsername(payload.username)
 userBuilder = userBuilder.setEmail(payload.email)

 val user = userBuilder.build()
```

Comment: I think `apply()` is intended for this sort of initialisation, more than `also()`.  (It dispenses with the `it.`, for one thing.)